# How to access specific log attributes in Kibana alert using mustache.js?

Tags: mustache, kibana-7

I am using `Kibana (version 7.1.1)` for my logging. I want to set up an `alert to Slack` channel based on some condition.

**What I have so far which is working:**

- Created an Alert with Monitor where I have set my condition.
- Created Trigger which has Slack web-hook integrated.
- I can send very basic message to slack channel when my condition is met.

**What I want:**

Kibana uses `mustache.js` and here, I can get my trigger name by doing `{{ctx.trigger.name}}` but I am not sure how can I get specific info from log such as `_source`.

Online research shows you can do `{{ ctx._source }}` or `{{ ctx.payload }}` but I don't see that in context. How can I get that?

[This is the link which is showing the parameters and most of them, I don't see in my context.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/how-watcher-works.html#watch-execution-context)

**ctx result:**

```
{
  monitor = {
    _id = ,
    _version = 1,
    name = Failed Order Alert,
    enabled = true
  }, trigger = {
    id = SOME-GUID,
    name = Failed Order Trigger,
    severity = 1,
    actions = [{
      name = JUST TESTING
    }]
  }, results = [{
    _shards = {
      total = 1,
      failed = 0,
      successful = 1,
      skipped = 0
    },
    hits = {
      hits = [],
      total = {
        value = 0,
        relation = eq
      },
      max_score = null
    },
    took = 8,
    timed_out = false
  }], periodStart = 2020 - 02 - 13 T16: 40: 10.055 Z, 
  periodEnd = 2020 - 02 - 13 T16: 41: 10.055 Z, 
  alert = null, 
  error = null
}
```

**Kibana Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a solution for this. What I learned here is, if your query does not produce any result then you would see the payload what I posted originally. Here, the issue was my query.

**What to do in such case:**

1. Make sure your query is correct. Here, if you have applied time frame than you need to check that too. This will be important.
2. Check your index is correct. This is seems obvious but can happen.

Assuming all this is corrected then you should see `results` in your output. It can be fetched like this. `{{ ctx.results.0.hits.hits.0._source.YOUR-OBJECT }}`